# Tidyeval splice operator !!! fails with ggplot's aes

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyeval

[The article discussing tidy evaluation in ggplot2](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-tidy-evaluation/) gives the impression that `aes()` now supports quasiquoation. However, I'm having problems getting it to work with the unquote-splice operator `!!!`.

```
library( ggplot2 )

## Predefine the mapping of symbols to aesthetics
v <- rlang::exprs( x=wt, y=mpg )

## Symbol-by-symbol unquoting works without problems
ggplot( mtcars, aes(!!v$x, !!v$y) ) + geom_point()

## But unquote splicing doesn't...
ggplot( mtcars, aes(!!!v) ) + geom_point()
# Error: Can't use `!!!` at top level
# Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

(Perhaps unsurprisingly) The same thing happens if the aesthetic mapping is moved to the geom:

```
ggplot( mtcars ) + geom_point( aes(!!v$x, !!v$y) )   # works
ggplot( mtcars ) + geom_point( aes(!!!v) )           # doesn't
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `aes()` takes `x` and `y` arguments and `!!!` only works within dots. We'll try to solve this particular problem in the future. In the interim you'll need to unquote `x` and `y` individually, or use the following workaround:

```
aes2 <- function(...) {
  eval(expr(aes(!!!enquos(...))))
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes2(!!!v)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you, @lionel.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround ([first described by Hadley](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2675#issuecomment-406893429)), the following code uses empty arguments to skip the named parameters in `aes`. That way, `!!!` works inside `aes`:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(, , !!! v))
```

Answer (score 0):

with the new rlang update, i think you can use {{}} to work inside ggplot

```
polo<- function(x,y, data, by) {

  ggplot({{data}}, aes(x = {{x}}, y = {{y}})) + 
    geom_point()  + 
    facet_grid(rows = vars({{by}}))
}
polo(data = mtcars, x = cyl, y = mpg, by = vs )
```

The only problem I face is with using facet_wrap. I have tried quo_name but that seems to not work with facet_wrap(~ quo_name(by)). Otherwise everything else just works. Although this as a workaround can also help, but I prefer to stick with facet_grid and vars[workaround](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/07/ggplot2-tidy-evaluation/).