# How to use tidy eval NSE to expand a `an expression`

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval, nse

I want to expand the `!!!` expression just like they do in dplyr-verbs e.g.

```r
aggregate_expressions <- list(n = quote(n()))

do_something(iris, !!!(aggregate_expressions))
```

and say I want `do_something` to perform

```
do_something <- function(...) {
  iris %>%
    some_function( # expand the ... # ) # some_function(n = n())
}
```

which will do this but the `n = n()` is dynamic

```
do_something <- function(...) {
  iris %>%
    some_function(n = n())
}
```

I tried to trace the code for `dplyr::summarise` and I see that `enquos(...)` which converts the `...` to a list of `quosure`, but then how do I *apply* the quosures? I think I am meant to create the code `summarise(n = n())` from the quosure and then evaluate i using `eval_tidy`, but I can't figure out how to generate the code. I know that pass ... `summarise` works but the actual use case is to pass it to `summarise.disk.frame` which means I can't just reuse `dplyr::summarise`

The actual case i not

For example in dplyr, the below works by expanding the `aggregate_expression` using `!!!`

```r
  aggregate_expressions <- list(n = quote(n()))

  iris %>%    
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(!!!(aggregate_expressions))
```

Comment: What's the end result you're trying to get exactly?

Comment: do_something <- function(...) {
  iris %>%
    summarise( # expand the ... # ) # summarise(n = n())
}

Comment: But what do you expect to get when you call `do_something(iris, !!!(aggregate_expressions))`?

Comment: updated to be more explicitly

Comment: Shouldn't you call only `do_something(!!!aggregate_expressions)`? You are calling `iris` inside the function, so no need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: BTW, your function should look like something like this: `do_something <- function(...) {
  groupvars <- quos(...)
  iris %>%
    summarise(!!!groupvars) # summarise(n = n())
}`

Comment: summarise is just an example. I mentioned in the post that dplyr:: summarise would just work but I wanted something more general, what if I want to do something other than summarise

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046162/300187

Answer (score 1):

Modify it like this:

```
do_something <- function(x) {
  iris %>%
    summarise(!!!x)
}

aggregate_expressions <- list(n = quote(n()))
do_something(aggregate_expressions)
##     n
## 1 150
```

Comment: (Just a note that for robustness it's better to create the list of expressions as quosures, e.g. with `vars()`.)

Comment: This is missing the point, because summarise(!!!x) works because summarise is designed to handle !!! but it won't work for some other function,

Comment: There was no example given for `do_something` other than the code which I took straight from the question.  Please fix the question and provide a complete example.