# !!! (splice operator) for ggplot2 geom_point() function

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

I am using !!! (splice operator/big bang operator) for ggplot2::geom_point() function, and it fails. Could someone point out what is wrong with this code? The following code tries to execute ggplot2 functions from character vectors.

```
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)
data = mtcars

assoc = c( "cyl" , "hp" )
names(assoc) = c("x", "y")
assoc_lang = rlang::parse_exprs(assoc)
gg = ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes( ,, !!! assoc_lang )) # This works

params = c( "10", "\"black\"" )
names(params) = c("size", "colour" )
params_lang = rlang::parse_exprs(params)
gg = gg + ggplot2::geom_point( !!! params_lang ) # This fails

plot(gg)
```

- output

```
Error in !params_lang : invalid argument type
Calls: <Anonymous> -> layer
Execution halted
```

(NOTE)
The following code is an equivalent one in an interactive manner, which shows what I want to do in the above code.

```
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)
data = mtcars

gg = ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes( x = cyl , y = hp ))
gg = gg + ggplot2::geom_point( size = 10, colour = "black")
plot(gg)
```

Comment: For searchability, the official name of this operator is now [splice operator](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These metaprogramming operators, including `{{…}}`, `!!` and `!!!` only work in quasiquotation functions. That is, functions whose arguments explicitly support tidy evaluation. In general, such function will explicitly mention quasiquotation support in their documentation.

Amongst these functions is `ggplot2::aes`, because it generally uses non-standard evaluation of its arguments. But other ‘ggplot2’ functions (including `ggplot2::geom_point`) perform standard evaluation of their arguments, and thus do not support any of these pseudo-operators.

If you want to dynamically construct a call to this function, you’ll need to go the conventional route, e.g. via (base R) `do.call`, or (‘rlang’) `exec` (or, manually, via `call` + `eval`/`call2` + `eval_tidy`).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It really clarifies why splice operator(!!!) works only for `ggplot2::aes. rlang::exec( "geom_point" , !!! params_lang )` finally works in my case!

Answer (score 2):

Konrad did an excellent job explaining why the function fails. I just want to make note of `rlang::inject()`, which allows you to introduce quasiquotation / non-standard evaluation to any function:

```
gg = gg + rlang::inject(ggplot2::geom_point( !!! params_lang ))

plot(gg)   # Now works
```

As a side note, your "This works" example is actually a very elegant answer to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815963/tidyeval-splice-operator-fails-with-ggplots-aes).

Comment: rlang::inject() works great, thanks!

Comment: About `ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes( ,, !!! assoc_lang ))`, I referred to this thread https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2675 .